# header files include conio.h?

Tags: c

why gcc does not include conio.h as a header file

Comment: The question you asked now might as well be answered by "perhaps you didn't tell it to". Show code, error message and everything else that's needed to answer.

Comment: Not a code question but my answer below does answer what he is asking for.

Comment: I think OP is asking why `conio.h` is not available on a unix system (or perhaps cygwin) with gcc. The answer of course is that `conio.h` is nonstandard legacy DOS junk.

Answer (score 2):

conio.h is DOS/Windows specific

Try ncurses